# Solr 4 MySQL Import

Tags: configuration, solr, migration

I'm attempting to move over to Solr 4 from 3.6 with MySQL support.  Previously in solr 3.x you were able to drop in the mysql driver in the /lib folder, which I have done, but that does not appear to work.

Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Do I need to add something in the configuration somewhere to look for this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the path for the shared folder for your jars.

in solr.xml just add `sharedLib="/path/to/your/lib"` in `<solr persistent="true">`  tag, then you are done...